# Django Multiple filter with range look-up

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter

my model:

```
class Attendance(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attendance = models.BooleanField()
```

the query i am trying

```
att = Attendance.objects.filter(date__range=(st_date,ls_date)).filter(student__range=(1,10))
```

it is giving me an error :

```
   File "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\backend\environment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1184, in build_lookup
    raise FieldError('Related Field got invalid lookup: {}'.format(lookup_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: range
```

Comment: What version of Django do you use?

Comment: Can you post the `Student` model?

Comment: Apparently, you cannot `__range` on the ForeignKey (`student`). It doesn't make a lot of sense to query `Student.pk` by range, anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to filter with a `student__range`, since there are no ranges of `Student`s : there is no inherent order, or a successor/predecessor.

You can for example constraint the *primary key* of the student, or some other numerical value, with:

```
Attendance.objects.filter(
    date__range=(st_date,ls_date),
    student__pk__range=(1,10)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only 10 of item from query u can use the `index`

```
att = Attendance.objects.filter(date__range=(st_date,ls_date))[0:9]
```